# Run goimports on save in Sublime Text?

Tags: go, sublimetext3, gofmt

In Sublime Text 3, with plugins `GoSublime` and `GoImports` installed.

I'm having trouble having `goimports` run on my file automatically everytime I save.

Here's what I tried :

My GoSublime settings are set to :

```
{
    "env": {"GOPATH": "/home/nicolas/.go", "PATH": "$GOPATH/bin:$PATH" },
    //"fmt_cmd": ["goimports"]
}
```

When I save with these settings, the code gets formatted but imports are not added. Nothing surprising so far.

If I hit ctrl+shift+P then GoImports, imports get added as expected.

Now my problem is, when I uncomment that previous line to have these settings :

```
{
    "env": {"GOPATH": "/home/nicolas/.go", "PATH": "$GOPATH/bin:$PATH" },
    "fmt_cmd": ["goimports"]
}
```

Not only does it not add the imports, but no other formatting gets done anymore.

Any idea where I went wrong ?

I'm using Linux (Ubuntu).

Comment: `goimports` probably isn't on your `$PATH`, or isn't executable.

Comment: Can you verify that you have done everything listed in the [following link ?](http://michaelwhatcott.com/gosublime-goimports/)

Comment: That was it. The thing is, I had installed GoImports through sublime using `Package control > Install plugin > GoImports`, and not through the `$ go get ... ` command. Which of course did put it in the sublime packages folder, not in $GOPATH/bin, which is on my $PATH. Gonna self-answer my question right away.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Make sure `$GOPATH/bin` is in your `$PATH` (Windows: `%GOPATH%\bin` goes
   in your `%PATH%`).
2. Run `go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports` (you may have to
   install mercurial).
3. Install Sublime Text and GoSublime (or make sure you’ve got the
   latest update if it’s already installed).
4. Open the GoSublime user `config/preference` file (Mac: `⌘. ⌘5` Windows:
   `Ctrl+. Ctrl+5`). Make sure you keep the command button down for the
   whole shortcut sequence.
5. Make it look like this:
   `{"fmt_cmd": ["goimports"]}`

[Source](http://michaelwhatcott.com/gosublime-goimports/)

Answer (score 3):

So, where I went wrong :

I installed GoImports from inside Sublime using `Package control > Install package > GoImports`. That installed it in the Sublime Packages folder, which was not on my `$PATH`

What I should have done instead :

Install it using the command `go get -u golang.org/x/tools/cmd/goimports`. This will install it in your `$GOPATH` (and `$GOPATH/bin` should be on your `$PATH`).

Answer (score 0):

`ctrl+. , ctrl+x` open `margo.go` file.
Then uncomment one of golang.GoFmt & golang.GoImports. restart sublime text and try again.

```
// golang.GoFmt,
// or
// golang.GoImports,
```

I using `ubuntu + sublime text 3207 + Go-1.10 + Gosublime + Goimports-release-1.10`. And it works for after I uncomment golang.GoImports.